# Не могу понять, почему не работает условие

Tags: c#

Кусок кода, который выделен звёздочками, почему - то всегда выдаёт `true`, не могу понять почему. Ведь, когда число больше 100 - должно выдавать `false`.

```
using System;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Пожалуйста, введите первое число:");
        var number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Пожалуйста, введите второе число:");
        var number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Пожалуйста, введите третье число:");
        var number3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (number1 > number2 && number1 > number3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Число {number1} самое большое из трёх чисел");

        }
        else if (number2 > number1 && number2 > number3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Число {number2} самое большое из трёх чисел");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Число {number3} самое большое из трёх чисел");
        }

        int parity1 = number1 % 2;
        int parity2 = number2 % 2;
        int parity3 = number3 % 2;

        switch (parity1)
         {
            case 0 :
                Console.WriteLine($"Число {number1} чётное");
                break;
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine($"Число {number1} нечётное");
                break;
        }
        switch (parity2)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine($"Число {number2} чётное");
                break;
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine($"Число {number2} нечётное");
                break;
        }
        switch (parity3)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine($"Число {number3} чётное");
                break;
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine($"Число {number3} нечётное");
                break;
        }

        ***bool check1 = number1 < 100 ? (number1 < 100) : (number1 > 100) ;
        Console.WriteLine(check1);***

            Console.Read();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool check1 = number1 < 100 ? (number1 < 100) : (number1 > 100) ;
```

На человеческом языке:

если переменная меньше ста, вернуть результат проверки меньше ли она ста. В противном случае, вернуть результат проверки больше ли она ста. Это вернет `false`, только если переменная равна ста.

```
bool check1 = number1 < 100;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @НикитаРассоха Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Это довольно просто)

Давайте прочитаем конструкцию:

```
number1 < 100 ? (number1 < 100) : (number1 > 100) ;

если number1 меньше 100, то 
  вернуть (number1 меньше 100?) 
иначе
  вернуть (number1 больше 100?)
```

Вы на C#, можно сказать, написали "масло масляное"

Если вы хотите получить в `check1` ответ на вопрос `number1 меньше 100?`, то достаточно написать

```
check1 = number1 < 100;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло